# Pass Exception from plugin to Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

For some reasons I have a javascript that create an entity record and a plugin will fire on post create. If the pugin throw an exception, it does NOT display to the user as the javascript is involved. I am wondering if there is a way to pass the exception from the plugin to javascrit so it can display it to the user.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you put a try catch in your javascript and throw an alert box up?

Comment: I tried that, but this still does NOT catch the exception thrown by the plugin.

Comment: Does the plugin throw a InvalidPluginExecutionException?

Comment: Yes the plugin is throwing InvalidPluginExecutionException and the JavaScript has the following try/catch: try{ .... } catch(err){ alert(err.message); }

Comment: To Clarify: JavaScipt is firing on the Save event for Entity A and then Create Entity B. A PlugIn fire on Entity B and throw an exception, that exception is NOT catched by the catch statement of the JavaScipt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of you. I did resolve the issue by modifying part of my code to the following:

```
 rec.send(jsonEntity);
  if (rec.readyState == 4) {
    if (rec.status >= 200) {
        var newRecord = JSON.parse(rec.responseText).d;
        return newRecord;
    }
    else {
           var error;
           var er;
        try { 
              error = rec.responseText.toString();
             error = error.substring(error.lastIndexOf("value\": ")+9,error.lastIndexOf("\""));
             alert(error);
              }
         catch(e) {
                error = rec.responseText.toString();
              error = encodeURIComponent(error);
            er = error.substring(error.lastIndexOf("value%22%3A%20%22")+17,
                             error.lastIndexOf("%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%7D"));
            er = decodeURIComponent(er);
              return er;
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you receive any http status code error like 40*, 500, 50* , if you use Odata, you have a callback to get the error. Javascript exception may not be throw.

Example:

```
.ajax({
type: “POST”,
contentType: “application/json; charset=utf-8″,
datatype: “json”,
url: serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + “/” + odataSetName,
data: jsonEntity,

beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
//Specifying this header ensures that the results will be returned as JSON.
XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader(“Accept”, “application/json”);

},
success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {

},

error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

if (errorCallback)

errorCallback(XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);

else

alert(“Error on the creation of record; Error – “+errorThrown);

}

});

}
```

Comment: Here is my code and I would appreciate it if you can help modify it using callback:

Comment: function createRecord(eObject, eName) {


var jsonEntity = window.JSON.stringify(eObject);


var u = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();


var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";


var rec = new XMLHttpRequest();


var p = u + ODATA_ENDPOINT;


rec.open('POST', p + "/" + eName, false);


rec.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");


rec.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");


rec.send(jsonEntity);


var r = JSON.parse(rec.responseText).d;

return r;

};

Answer (score 0):

Checking the XMLHttpRequest readyState and status should do the trick:

```javasscript
function createRecord(eObject, eName) {
    var jsonEntity = window.JSON.stringify(eObject);
    var u = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();
    var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";
    var rec = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var p = u + ODATA_ENDPOINT;
    rec.open('POST', p + "/" + eName, false);
    rec.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    rec.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    rec.send(jsonEntity);
    if (rec.readyState == 4) {
        if (rec.status == 200) {
            var r = JSON.parse(rec.responseText).d;
            return r;
        }
        else {
            var error;
            try { 
                // To get the exception from the responseXML
                // I get an error when trying to use JSON.parse(rec.response)
                // Unexpected token <
                // I would much rather use JSON.parse 
                // than fiddling with the XML
                // Please let me know if you find how to 
                // get the error message with JSON.parse
                var xmlDoc = rec.responseXML;
                var error = xmlDoc.childNodes[0]
                    .childNodes[0]
                    .childNodes[0]
                    .childNodes[1]
                    .childNodes[0].nodeValue + "."; // The error message
            }
            catch (e) {
                // unable to get error message from response
                error = "General Error"; 
            }
            return error;
        }
    }
    // there is a problem
    // maybe return general error message
    return "General Error";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think req.responseXML should be req.responseXML.XML. When I use that I am getting null, so the error is always "General Error".

Comment: You can use console.log(rec.responseXML) and then press F12 in IE or Chrome to view the object, rec.responseXML was working for me, but maybe it is not supported by some browsers; rec.response might be a safer option. Also I just noticed that I was using req instead of rec as the name of the XMLHttpRequest; I will change it now.

Comment: My problem is because of the error I am getting from rec.response which is:                                                                                {
"error": {
"code": "-2147220891", "message": {
"lang": "en-US", "value": "'Type' Does NOT Exists !."
}
}
}                                                                                                                                         JavaScript CANNOT display such error using alert since it has characters like '{' , '"' etc.                                                                 Any idea please how to display such error?

Comment: My plugin has the following line of code to throw exception:                                                                                                                           throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("\'Type\' Does NOT Exists !.");

Comment: You could try to use JSON.parse(req.response) to get at the response text otherwise tunneling down into the XML with .childNodes should work. Are you able to use JSON.parse on req.response?

Comment: using JSON.parse(rec.response) throwing "Invalid Character" error.

Comment: I got the same. Have you tried using .childNodes on the xmlDoc? You can use console.log to find the right one by trial and error.